# I run a unit test with Arquillian, but the console shows me an error

Tags: junit, ejb, inject, jboss-arquillian

I run the test:

```
   @RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class GreeterTest {

    @Inject
    Greeter greeter;

    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
        JavaArchive jar = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
                .addClass(Greeter.class)
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
        System.out.println(jar.toString(true));
        return jar;
    }

    @Test
    public void should_create_greeting() {
        Assert.assertEquals("Hello, Earthling!",
                greeter.createGreeting("Earthling"));
        greeter.greet(System.out, "Earthling");
    }

}
---------------
package com.teste;

import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Greeter {

    public void greet(PrintStream to, String name) {
        to.println(createGreeting(name));
    }

    public String createGreeting(String name) {
        return "Hello, " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

My pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com</groupId>
<artifactId>teste</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

But an error is caused.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ejb/Stateless   at
>   org.jboss.arquillian.container.weld.ee.embedded_1_1.mock.Ejbs.findEjbs(Ejbs.java:38)...

Anyone know what can be? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution to the problem, adding some dependencies.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing EE things. You can just pull in the whole dependency instead of individual ones.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomee</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0-3</version>
        </dependency>
```